# Sympy Fourier Transform of exponential decay

Tags: python, transform, fft, sympy, exponential

Sympy correctly computes the FT of a double-sided exponential decay:

```
x, k, k0 = symbols('x k k0')
fourier_transform(exp(-k0 * abs(x)), x, k)
```

--> 2k0 / (4pi^2k^2 + k0^2)

Expected by hand calculation and confirmed by http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/decayingexponential.php

I tried to do the same thing for a single-sided exponential decay by defining a Piecewise function where the function returns 0 for x<0 and exp(-abs(k0)x) for x >=0

```
f = exp(-abs(k0)*x)
ssexp = Piecewise( (0,x<0), (f, x>=0))
fourier_transform(ssexp, x, k)
```

The output (I don't know how to insert formatted equations) just returns:

```
Fx[{0 for x<0, e-x|k0| for x>=0](k)
```

The LaTeX code for the output is
$$
\mathcal{F}*{x}\left[\begin{cases} 0 & \text{for}: x < 0 \e^{- x \left\lvert{k*{0}}\right\rvert} & \text{for}: x \geq 0 \end{cases}\right]\left(k\right)
$$

I've looked for examples of this kind of FT done within Python/Sympy but have not found anything.

The analytical FT of a Gaussian also works fine.  Perhaps Piecewise isn't the right tool for this or I've made some other rookie mistake.

Suggestions appreciated.

The Old Guy in the Club

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Heaviside function rather than Piecewise seems to be the way to go here:

```
>>> fourier_transform(f*Heaviside(x), x, k)
1/(2*I*pi*k + Abs(k0))
```

But in the most recent version of SymPy, the expression you gave also works for me:

```
>>> fourier_transform(ssexp, x, k)
1/(2*I*pi*k + Abs(k0))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm going to mark this as answered but I am intrigued by your ability to get the original FT to work. I tried it on 3 installations,  Windows,  Mac, and Linux.  All have the most recent sympy AFAIK and all didn't evaluate it!

Comment: I think he means the git version (or you can use the 0.7.6.rc2 release candidate, which will be released as a final version later this week).

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  The leading-edge code and git is beyond my abilities!  I'll try it again after the update comes out.